# How to resolve overload method using generic ( java )

Tags: java

```
public void put(String str);
public void put(Integer in);
public void put(Boolean bol);

public <T> void putGeneric(T value)
{
    put(value);
}
```

This code show error "can not resolve method"

Comment: Actually, I'm c++ guy. I don't know why this doesn't work

Comment: You need to cast `T` to a specific type

Comment: Please show the full code, this code, as it is, is incomplete and it has hard to pin point the exact issue.

Comment: `T` could be anything, what if it is a `Car`? Java has a strong type system and will not allow this code as it would be possible to call it wrong. The generic system works very different to C++. When the method is evaluated, the call-sites are ignored, unlike to C++ where generic methods are basically always valid and only the call-site has to follow the restrictions.

Comment: Also, if `T` were a `Long` or just `Object`, what would you _expect_ it to call? I don't think having one method per type is going to scale very well here and defeats the point of generics

Comment: @OneCricketeer T is one of String, Integer, Boolean

Comment: _T is one of..._ According to what? Java doesn't know that on its own.

Comment: "*T is one of String, Integer, Boolean*" no you can't force that restriction with classes in Java. For now `T` can be *some type* without excluding any type like for instance `Car`. So your generic method would accept argument like `putGeneric(new Car("BMW"))` but can't support it. Generics are not solution to every problem.

Comment: Javas generic system will not consider the call-sites. It does not matter that you only call it valid. The point is that you could call it invalid. That alone is enough to Java to forbid it. Unlike C++, the generic method itself has to be _100% valid_ in itself. In C++ only the call-site has to _make sense_. Id suggest you learn more about how generics work in Java and throw away your thinking of C++ templates. The differences are huge, also in the way they are used. For example, in C++ templates are often used to form interfaces (concepts in C++20), in Java we create an `interface` instead.

Comment: @Zabuzard Ok... I understand. I think this is for preventing mistake. But I can't understand this as c++ programer................

Comment: Well, in C++, the generic method is basically always valid and compiles. And then, when seeing the call-site, C++ copy pastes the method and substitutes the given type in and only then checks if it compiles (if not, the call-site is considered invalid, not the method). Java doesnt do it like that at all. The generic method itself is checked already and has tight type restrictions. Java does not care how your call-site looks like. It checks your generic method individually and sees _"okay, we know nothing about T, it could be a Car... this method doesnt make sense with a Car, its invalid"_.

Comment: ... hence why we usually create an interface to group the properties and capabilities we need from our types and then restrict the generic to that type `T extends Foo`, then we can use everything from `Foo` at least (similar to how C++20 changes stuff with `concept`s). However, this only really works if your types actually do have something in common you want to group. It is not ideal for grouping arbitrary types like you attempt. However, chances are that your setup is already kinda broken and maybe you should move the generics even further down for a nice architecture. Hard to guess though.

Comment: Ultimately, the exact way you are trying to use Java generics here (like C++ templates) is not really possible. At least not without sacrificing compile-time safety (see Cactusroots answers for a runtime-safe variant). You have to step back and change the approach/design of whatever you are trying to create here, on a higher level. For this, we would need to get more details about the code though.

Comment: As a C++ developer the most important thing you must learn about Java generics is that they are nothing like C++ templates. It's best to learn them from scratch and not associate them with templates at all. The *only* thing they have in common is that they are sometimes used for similar things (like defining the content of some container class). But implementation-wise they are *very* different. Don't try to apply your C++ intuitions to Java generics.

Answer (score 0):

> T is one of String, Integer, Boolean

Based on these requirements, you cannot enforce this at the class level using generics.

If you want to be able to pass though these three types, you can use a cascaded try-catch and only allow a string representation of those types

For example,

```
void putGeneric(String s) { 
  try { 
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s); 
    put(i);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    if (s.matches("true|false") {
      put(Boolean.parseBoolean(s));
    } else {
      put(s); 
    }
  }
}
```

More specifically, you need to coerce the types into the specific methods

Comment: I have the feeling that OP is mainly confused due to their C++ background. Templates do allow that, cause C++ will basically allow any generic method and pass the requirements of _does it make sense_ one level up to all call-sites. Basically "_as long as the method compiles with the call-site given type, its cool_", which primarily is because of how C++ templates work (basically copy&paste with type substitution).

Comment: Using try-catch creates an Exception-Object because of the thrown Exception. I would consider using if-else for this performance reason.

Comment: @Cactusroot You are right with the downside, but there is no easy way to check if the string represent an integer other than this. (Regex or similar will fail at checking the upper and lower limit of the int range).

Comment: @Cactusroot Not sure I understand. try-catch doesn't "create an exception object". How would you use an if-else on `Integer.parseInt`?

Answer (score 0):

Here T is generic type and the JVM is also confused to which type it should resolve . This functionality should be better implemented having one method  called Put and which accepts generic type as the operations is common for all types .

Generics are used where functions do same work regardless to the input parameter , lets say add(x,y) method  will add Integers , double... this type of method definition requires generic implemented .

Comment: I have the feeling that OP is mainly confused due to their C++ background. Templates do allow that, cause C++ will basically allow any generic method and pass the requirements of does it make sense one level up to all call-sites. Basically "as long as the method compiles with the call-site given type, its cool", which primarily is because of how C++ templates work (basically copy&paste with type substitution).

Answer (score 0):

The error is shown because you don't have any method that accepts every Object so no method is fitting.

You need to exactly tell Java what `value` is:

```
public void put(String str);
public void put(Integer in);
public void put(Boolean bol);

public <T> void putGeneric(T value) {
    if (value instanceof String) put((String) value);
    else if (value instanceof Integer) put((Integer) value);
    else if (value instanceof Boolean) put((Boolean) value);
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("value has wrong type. Type: " + T + " value: " + value);
}
```

Or just leave the `put()`-methods public and access them directly.

Comment: While this works, it kinda defeats the purpose of the strong type system that generics provide. Because this allows compilation of `putGeneric(new Car())`, the error is pushed to runtime instead of compile time, a major step back when it comes to bug detection...

Comment: You are right, but there is no better way of doing it if you just want to access one single method. I added a note saying that you can directly use the put()-methods, but maybe you might want to do something with the value if it does not fit.

Answer (score -1):

Your `putGeneric` method is `generic` not `put` method. Therefore before calling the `put` method you need to `typecast` the object.
you can call put as below:

```
public <T> void putGeneric(T value) {
        if (value instanceof String) {
            put((String) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
            put((Integer) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            put((Boolean) value);
        } else {
             throw new ClassCastException("unsupported class!!!");
        }

    }
```

Comment: While this works, it kinda defeats the purpose of the strong type system that generics provide. Because this allows compilation of `putGeneric(new Car())`, the error is pushed to runtime instead of compile time, a major step back when it comes to bug detection...

Comment: As a note, instead of printing "Operation not supported", you should throw an exception. For example `UnsupportedOperationException`, `IllegalArgumentException` or `ClassCastException` maybe.

Comment: In addition to abusing generics, this also doesn't really add anything over just `putGeneric(Object value)` without any generics.